# ¿Como hacer para cuando no se recibe un file de igual forma se guarde como null en PHP y MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma para que cuando no se reciba un archivo de imagen de igual forma sin que sucedan errores se guarde en la base de datos como null. La base de datos si está aceptando archivos null, pero cuando un usuario no selecciona una imagen entonces ocurre un error.

Por ejemplo, tengo este formulario para 5 imagenes, sin embargo van a haber ocaciones donde el usuario no introduzca una imagen, por lo que eso me genera un error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código para guardar esas imagenenes en el model:

```
$imagen1 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name']));
$imagen2 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen2']['tmp_name']));
$imagen3 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen3']['tmp_name']));
$imagen4 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen4']['tmp_name']));
$imagen5 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen5']['tmp_name']));

$agregarPropiedad = $instancia -> query("CALL SP_PROPIEDADES_INSERTAR('$imagen1', '$imagen2', '$imagen3', '$imagen4', '$imagen5');");
```

Solamente cuando selecciono las 5 imagenes la funcion corre sin ningun problema, pero si solo guardo una se cae. Si hubiera una forma para guardar una imagen predefinida cuando el valor es null o simplemente no guardar nada estaría genial.

Comment: Antes de hacer la asignación de imagen1,imagen2... comprueba que exista el índice en el array de $_FILES. Mira array_key_exists en el manual de php. Si existe asignas el file_gdt_contents, sino asignas null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
$total_imagenes = 5;
$valores = '';
for ($i = 1; $i < $total_imagenes+1; $i++) {
    ${'imagen'.$i} = !empty($_FILES['imagen'.$i]['tmp_name']) ? addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen'.$i]['tmp_name'])) : null;
    $valores .= "'".${'imagen'.$i}."',";
}
$valores = rtrim($valores, ",");
$agregarPropiedad = $instancia -> query("CALL SP_PROPIEDADES_INSERTAR(".$valores.");");
```

### Explicación

El principal problema descrito en la pregunta eran los errores ocasionados cuando no se seleccionaban algunas imágenes, los cuales venian dados porque no se verificaba si las variables $_FILES de todas las imágenes tenian datos, dando por supuesto que siempre existirían, pues de hecho era la única forma de conseguir que funcionara.

Esto venia dado por este tipo de instrucciones:

```
$imagen1 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name']));
```

donde, repito, no se verificaba si todas las variables  `$_FILES['imagenX']['tmp_name']` tenian datos primero, y provocando error cuando no se subian todos los archivos de imagen esperados.

La solución fácil y repetitiva hubiera sido comprobarlo de esta forma en cada caso:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['imagenX']['tmp_name'])) {
  $imagenX = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagenX']['tmp_name']));
} else {
  $imagenX = null;
}
```

o bien en su forma abreviada con el operador ternario `?:` :

```
  $imagenX = (!empty($_FILES['imagenX']['tmp_name'])) ? addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagenX']['tmp_name'])) : null;
```

pero eso, aunque funcionaría bien, hubiera sido demasiado repetitivo desde mi punto de vista, y he preferido encerrarlo todo en un bucle donde se pudiera escoger el número de imágenes sin tener que cambiar el resto del código de este modo:

```
$total_imagenes = 5;
$valores = '';
for ($i = 1; $i < $total_imagenes+1; $i++) {
    ${'imagen'.$i} = !empty($_FILES['imagen'.$i]['tmp_name']) ? addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen'.$i]['tmp_name'])) : null;
    $valores .= "'".${'imagen'.$i}."',";
}
$valores = rtrim($valores, ",");
$agregarPropiedad = $instancia -> query("CALL SP_PROPIEDADES_INSERTAR(".$valores.");");
```

**donde:**

- definimos una variable que nos indica el total de imagenes que esperamos recibir:

```
$total_imagenes = 5;
```

- inicializamos la cadena de valores a pasarle a la query:

```
$valores = '';
```

- recorremos las imagenes esperadas, sabiendo que empiezan por 1:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $total_imagenes+1; $i++) {
```

- realizamos la asignación de las variables de cada imagen:

```
    ${'imagen'.$i} = !empty($_FILES['imagen'.$i]['tmp_name']) ? addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen'.$i]['tmp_name'])) : null;
```

ojo con esta línea, pues aquí jugamos con que esto:

```
${'imagen'.$i}
```

en el fondo es una forma de expresar esta variable:

```
$imagenX
```

donde la X va siendo sustituida por la $i en cada ciclo.

- finalmente, dentro del ciclo, vamos concatenando los valores mediante esta línea:

```
    $valores .= "'".${'imagen'.$i}."',";
```

- ya fuera del bucle, lo que hacemos es eliminar la última coma `,` de la variable $valores mediante esta instrucción:

```
$valores = rtrim($valores, ",");
```

- y por último, insertamos $valores en la query:

```
$agregarPropiedad = $instancia -> query("CALL SP_PROPIEDADES_INSERTAR(".$valores.");");
```

dando por supuesto que $valores contiene más o menos esto (aunque ya con sus valores finales, que pueden ser **null** o bien el resultado del **file_get_contents**):

```
'$imagen1', '$imagen2', '$imagen3', '$imagen4', '$imagen5'
```

Comment: Si me ha funcionado de maravilla! Te agradezco mucho!

Que pasa en el caso de que quiera modificar imagenes, debo usar el mismo metodo?

Comment: mmm... no se como seria para modificarlas... supongo que te refieres a sobreescribirlas... no se, tendria que ver el formulario que tengas para eso... entiendo que lo que haciamos ahora era para insertar solamente

Comment: por cierto, recuerda aceptar esta respuesta si te ha servido, así la comunidad lo sabrá también.  Luego pondré la explicación (ahora debo salir un rato, lo siento)

Comment: Gracias amigo! Voy a hacer otro ticket y te envío el enlace para que veas como lo tengo.

Comment: He visto que el proceso de guardarlas funciona correctamente al darle click en el boton guardar, pero cuando reviso la base de datos en realidad no me las guarda. He modificado imagem por imagen y me sale este error.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trabajo\Real-State\model\PropiedadesModel.php:47 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Trabajo\Real-State\model\PropiedadesModel.php(47): file_get_contents('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Trabajo\Real-State\View\Admin\IngresarPropiedad.php(77): GuardarInformacionPropiedad() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trabajo\Real-State\model\PropiedadesModel.php on line 47

Comment: ¿y antes, con el sistema de tu pregunta inicial, te las guardaba?  Es decir, si el problema está en esto a mi se me escapa lo que hace pues no aparece en la pregunta:  `$agregarPropiedad = $instancia -> query("CALL SP_PROPIEDADES_INSERTAR(".$valores.");");`

Comment: El error no deberia aparecerte si en todos los sitios has puesto imagen (con **n**... lo de la M de antes era una error de tipeo mio que no debe aparecer en el código), pues tal como acabo de explicar, antes de usar el file_get_contents estamos verificando si esa variable existe... a menos que ya exista pero nos venga con un valor null directamente, en cuyo caso deberemos modificar el `isset($_FILES['imagen'.$i]['tmp_name'])` por `isset($_FILES['imagen'.$i]['tmp_name']) && !is_null($_FILES['imagen'.$i]['tmp_name'])`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137456/discussion-between-ivan-coto-jimenez-and-masterguru).

Comment: @IvánCotoJiménez alguna novedad?   ya está solucionado? o queda algo pendiente?

Comment: Hola! @masterguru aun no lo logro solucionar

Comment: He visto el comentario que te han dado [en esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/544147/como-insertar-una-imagen-como-null-cuando-el-usuario-no-la-digita-en-php-y-mysql) y he modificado el código de esta respuesta para que sea el correcto, cambiando los `isset` por `!empty`

Comment: Te agradezco de igual forma amigo, muchas gracias!!!