# Como insertar una imagen como null cuando el usuario no la digita en PHP y MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Hola quisiera saber si puedo insertar un valor null cuando una imagen no es introducida por el usuario, **la idea es que sean 5 imagenes pero pueden haber ocaciones donde el usuario solo desee insertar 1 o 2 etc**. Ahorita mismo estoy validando que si entra la imagen entonces que se guarde la imagen, pero si no la seleccionan entonces que se guarde como null pero me da el siguiente error.

**Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trabajo\Real-State\model\PropiedadesModel.php:51 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Trabajo\Real-State\model\PropiedadesModel.php(51): file_get_contents('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Trabajo\Real-State\View\Admin\IngresarPropiedad.php(77): GuardarInformacionPropiedad() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trabajo\Real-State\model\PropiedadesModel.php on line 51**

La función que uso en el model es la siguiente

```
              if (isset($_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name'])) {
                $imagen1 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name']));
              } else {
                $imagen1 = null;
              }
              if (isset($_FILES['imagen2']['tmp_name'])) {
                $imagen2 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen2']['tmp_name']));
              } else {
                $imagen2 = null;
              }
              if (isset($_FILES['imagen3']['tmp_name'])) {
                $imagen3 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen3']['tmp_name']));
              } else {
                $imagen3 = null;
              }
              if (isset($_FILES['imagen4']['tmp_name'])) {
                $imagen4 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen4']['tmp_name']));
              } else {
                $imagen4 = null;
              }
              if (isset($_FILES['imagen5']['tmp_name'])) {
                $imagen5 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen5']['tmp_name']));
              } else {
                $imagen5 = null;
              }

$agregarPropiedad = $instancia -> query("CALL SP_PROPIEDADES_INSERTAR('$imagen1', '$imagen2', '$imagen3', '$imagen4', '$imagen5');");
```

Luego en el controller llamo a la funcion y la muestro en la vista llamando la funcion del controller, cabe resaltar que la base de datos si acepta null y el espacio para la imagen es de tipo LONGBLOB.

**Segundo intento**

Lo intenté hacer de esta otra forma, pero me da el mismo error.

```
$total_imagenes = 5;
$valores = '';
for ($i = 1; $i < $total_imagenes+1; $i++) {
  ${'imagen'.$i} = isset($_FILES['imagen'.$i]['tmp_name']) ? addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen'.$i]['tmp_name'])) : null;
  $valores .= "'".${'imagen'.$i}."',";
              }
  $valores = rtrim($valores, ",");

}

$agregarPropiedad = $instancia -> query("CALL SP_PROPIEDADES_INSERTAR(".$valores.");");
```

Pense en la opción de insertar una imagen default cuando no se selecciona nada, pero no sé como pasar la imagen default y tampoco sé si eso sería factible por el espacio del servidor.

Comment: Tienes en el formulario creados los 5 input de tipo file? Si es así, la comprobación no puede ser isset, porque siempre van a llegar definidos. En su lugar prueba con !empty para comprobar que llega algún valor

Comment: OMG te agradezco demasiado, se ha solucionado. Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

La solución a mi problema sería la siguiente:

Se crea la vista en el la carpeta de view con el formulario de entrada y se le asigna un nombre a cada input, par utilizar ese nombre en el model de la siguiente forma:

```
              if (!empty($_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name'])) {
                $imagen1 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name']));
              } else {
                $imagen1 = null;
              }
              if (!empty($_FILES['imagen2']['tmp_name'])) {
                $imagen2 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen2']['tmp_name']));
              } else {
                $imagen2 = null;
              }
              if (!empty($_FILES['imagen3']['tmp_name'])) {
                $imagen3 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen3']['tmp_name']));
              } else {
                $imagen3 = null;
              }
              if (!empty($_FILES['imagen4']['tmp_name'])) {
                $imagen4 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen4']['tmp_name']));
              } else {
                $imagen4 = null;
              }
              if (!empty($_FILES['imagen5']['tmp_name'])) {
                $imagen5 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen5']['tmp_name']));
              } else {
                $imagen5 = null;
              }

$agregarPropiedad = $instancia -> query("CALL SP_PROPIEDADES_INSERTAR('$imagen1', '$imagen2', '$imagen3', '$imagen4', '$imagen5');");
```

Y en el controler se llama a la función de insertar para luego en la vista llamar a la funcion del controller.